# Visual Studio 2013 update 3 crashes while exploring MS ACCESS DB

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

When I try to add a MS ACCESS db to VS2013 and try to explore a table in it, Visual Studio crashes.
Check attached image, just right clicking on tables will crash the visual studio.

Just a specific .mdb file crashes VS, other newly created .mdb files open perfectly!

[image]

Comment: What version of Jet (3.5, 4.0) or Ace (12, 14, 15) is in use? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine gives you a mapping of Access version --> Jet/Ace version.

Comment: Have you tried a compact and repair on the mdb or accdb in question? Could be a corruption issue. **BACK UP THE FILE FIRST, before the compaction**.

Comment: FYI: Compact & Repair didn't solve the problem

Comment: How can I find ACE or JET version. Where are latest updates?

Comment: What version of access was used to create the database? Does it have an .mdb or .accdb extension?

Comment: It has .mdb extension and I can open other .mdb files here, but this specific file, mydb.mdb, crashes VS.

Comment: It's probably Jet 4.0. Let me try creating a blank mdb and connecting to it.

Comment: I tried blank db, it works fine, but this specific .mdb crashes.

Comment: Oh... really? Is it an option to export all of the objects out of the mdb into a blank one, to see if that fixes it?

Comment: I converted DB to .accdb still crashes, tried to remove relations in db, again crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted queries in .mdb, one by one, found one of them guilty.
It was just a simple joined query, nothing special, but by deleting it VS Server Explorer started exploring my database.

Comment: That's incredibly odd. If you recreate the query (copy and paste it back in), does it fail again? What's the query text? (feel free to sanitize it to remove your table names). Last thought: are any of the objects in the query using reserved keywords in their names?